# Navigation with React navigation Error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am coding a mobile app in React Native in Typescript, I am trying to navigate between two pages (Login, Signup), I can achieve what I want but VS Code is telling me there's an error on the route:

[image]

I need your help to know what is happening?

Thank you

Comment: I think it's an error with ESLint. You need to check this [https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/).

Comment: Please share the error/warn message as well

Comment: This the error : No overload matches this call.
  Argument of type '[string]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(options: never): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2769)

Comment: Thank you @RohitAggarwal for your help i didn,t read this page ;)